# What did Blackberry do wrong?

Tags: cryptography, hash, mobile, blackberry

The NIST defines [a vulnerability in RIM Blackberry encryption](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-3741) discovered last October.

Apparently, Blackberry's flavour of PBKDF2 was weak. They say:

> The offline backup mechanism in Research In Motion (RIM) BlackBerry Desktop Software uses **single-iteration PBKDF2**, which makes it easier for local users to decrypt a .ipd file via a brute-force attack.

*[Note: emphasis added.]*

What does "*single-iteration*" mean?

Does it mean that the fourth PBKDF2 parameter was 1? (Considering the function
`PBKDF2 (HMAC, password, salt, nbiterations, length)`.)

Or do we actually have to feed the result of PBKDF2 to itself, over and over again, a great number of times?

Comment: Title could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the PDF of the standard

ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2-0.pdf

That shows (page 4 & 5) that RIM set nbiterations as 1.

Here's a more general overview for people wanting a bit of easy to read background:
(It's a blog post of a company selling products which they mention on that page, with a single text link.)

http://blog.crackpassword.com/2010/09/smartphone-forensics-cracking-blackberry-backup-passwords/

Comment: The first link is broken.